# what is the solution of prompt window can not be show while apply sso with active directory using Window auth

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have Developed an app in Blazor server using the active directory with window authentication when Deploy on iss server access from the same domain with ips then Every time ask cardinals prompt open. I want when access from the same domain then the prompt can not be open access to direct to the site.
here is the code

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                spinnerService.Show();
                var authState = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
                var user = authState.User;
                var fullName = user.Identity.Name;
                var username = fullName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault() ?? fullName;
                Username = username;
                UserPrincipal principal = GetUserPrincipal(Username);
                if (principal != null)
                {
                    var groupList = principal.GetGroups().ToList();
                    // Specify the target group name
                   
                    if (groupList.Any(group => AdminGroupNames.Contains(group.Name)) && isAdmin)
                    {
                        isAdmin = true; //to get All Request for Admin User;
                        IsAuthorized = true;
                    }
                    else if (groupList.Any(group => UserGroupNames.Contains(group.Name)) && isAdmin != true)
                    {
                        isAdmin = true; //to get  Request for  User;
                        IsAuthorized = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        IsAuthorized = false;
                        spinnerService.Hide();

                    }

                    await PopulateGovtEntities();
                    await Load();
                    translationState.TranslateGridFilterLabels(grid);
                    spinnerService.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    spinnerService.Hide();
                    notificationService.Notify(new NotificationMessage()
                    {

                        Severity = NotificationSeverity.Error,
                        Detail = translationState.Translate("User_not_found"),

                        Style = "position: fixed !important; left: 0; margin: auto; "
                    });
                }



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                spinnerService.Hide();
                throw;
            }

        }
get user and group from active directory.
        public UserPrincipal GetUserPrincipal(string username)
        {
            try
            {
                // Construct a PrincipalContext for the domain
                PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
                // Find the user by the Windows identity name
                UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, username);
                if (userPrincipal != null)
                {
                    // Check if the user is a member of any of the specified admin groups.
                    foreach (string groupName in AdminGroupNames)
                    {
                        GroupPrincipal adminGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Name, groupName);
                        if (adminGroup != null && userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(adminGroup))
                        {
                            isAdmin = true;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    spinnerService.Hide();
                    notificationService.Notify(new NotificationMessage()
                    {

                        Severity = NotificationSeverity.Error,
                        Detail = translationState.Translate("User_not_found"),

                        Style = "position: fixed !important; left: 0; margin: auto; "
                    });
                }
                return userPrincipal;
            }
            catch (PrincipalServerDownException)
            {
                notificationService.Notify(new NotificationMessage()
                {
                    Severity = NotificationSeverity.Error,
                    Detail = translationState.Translate("Unable_to_connect_server"),
                    Style = "position: fixed !important; left: 0; margin: auto; "
                });

                spinnerService.Hide();
                return null;

            }
        }
```

Please any solution to this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFEIP.png)

I want when access from the same domain then not show the prompt window like in images.